# How to scope and persist claims to different clients in IdentityServer 3?

Tags: identityserver3, claims

I'm new to IdentityServer3 and have multiple MVC clients where users have claims which potentially could conflict and give undesired authorization.

Here is an example with two clients able to send emails and notifications to the users. A user might have access to both applications but should only be able to recieve notifications in Application A. How can we prevent the user from recieving notifications in Application B?

```
Application A
Claim Type: ApplicationFunctionality Claim Value:
RecieveNotifications
Claim Type: ApplicationFunctionality Claim Value: RecieveEmails

Application B
Claim Type: ApplicationFunctionality Claim Value: RecieveEmails
```

Would a resonable solution be to implement somekind of logic in a class using the IUserService interface?

Would it be correct to use claims in the way I described above across multiple clients, where we sometimes reuse claims for cross-client functionality. I guess it would require me to namespace the claims (perhaps using the requested scope name the client sends to IdentityServer) in order to distinguish claims for different clients and prevent unauthorized access between the clients.

Here is an example of user claim types/claim values:

```
Name: John Doe
Email: john.doe@acme.com
PreferedLanguages: English,Swedish,Spanish
ApplicationFunctionality: ClientA.RecieveEmails
ApplicationFunctionality: ClientB.RecieveEmails
ApplicationFunctionality: ClientA.RecieveNotifications
ApplicationFunctionality: ClientB.RecieveNotifications
ApplicationFunctionality: ClientA.ViewBackorders
ApplicationFunctionality: ClientA.DeleteBackorder
ApplicationFunctionality: ClientB.SearchProductInformation
CompanyID: 1145
CompanyID: 6785
CompanyName: Acme Inc
ApplicationLicense: ClientA.PayingNormalUser
ApplicationLicense: ClientB.FreeUser
```

A user from Company Acme Inc have several CompanyID's which is used when filtering data we request from webservices\databases in the data layer. The user have access to multiple applications where he/she could have different levels of functionality depending on what license they have bought in the applications. Some functionality exist in multiple clients but that doesn't mean the user are authorized to same functionality in all clients he/she have access to.

I would appreciate some guidelines about claims, or perhaps point me to some good resources about the subject. I have read that claims primary is used for identity related information (email, name, department, favorite color, shoe size etc), but if no role\permissions style claims should be used with claims then how should information about what a user is authorized to do in the clients be persisted and how should data be filtered in webservices/databases (resource providers) so the user only sees data he/she are authorized to see?

My first thoughts where that the id_token and access token would be convenient to use since they are issued by the STS (IdentityServer) and then later persisted in cookies. The STS would first be required to perform lookup of user account in Active Directory which contains user identity related information together with an lookup (using the username of the Active Directory user account) in custom database containing information about role\permissions and claims of the user.

How should I persist the roles/permissions and claims of a user if not using cookie persisted tokens provided by IdentityServer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clients (applications) and users can have their own set of claims. It looks like you want to have applications which have access to different resources. This is where you should use scopes. Basically define two scopes which define action on that resource (this is one common way of doing it) ie one for 'reading' emails and one for 'writing' emails (eg `emails.read` and `emails.write`) subsequently the other scopes can be `backorders.read` and `backorders.delete`. It's just good practice to have consistent naming here.

Ok now since weve defined those two scopes, you can now define two clients, one which has only the `emails.read` scope and the other one has both the read and write scopes. All this means is that one client has access to more resources than the other.

All the user identity claims should stick to the user itself. Application/client specific should never be associated with the user. `Name`,`Email`,`ApplicationLicense`, and `PreferredLanguages` are all valid claims for the user because they describe the user itself and what can be asserted about them.

For "complex" authorization you may want to look at [this](https://github.com/leastprivilege/AspNetCoreSecuritySamples/tree/master/Authorization) sample for some ideas on how to set up compound security policies or authorization.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to expose a different value to different clients for the same claim. This seems like a logical thing to want to do, especially if you are integrating with clients that are not within your control and thus cannot dictate to them what to expect in each claim, or what scopes to request. A simple example might be the "roles" claim - you may wish to send different values depending on the app that's making the request. If you're joining someone else's enterprise, perhaps with multiple OpenID Connect Providers, you don't always have a choice over the scopes or claim names.

I feel that Nat Sakimura eludes to this in the OpenID Connect FAQ video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kb56GzQ2pSk (1 minute 40s), the idea that an entity might want to expose a different identity to different clients.

In terms of implementation, we've added a table with [identityId, clientId, attributeName, attributeValue] to allow us to store the same identity attribute for different clients. In our case, these identity attributes become claims in the outgoing JWT. As most attributes about a user are global (i.e. not client specific), we treat the data in this table as overrides to a base set, which saves duplicating the same data for each client unnecessarily. The iUserService.GetProfileDataAsync() method has access to the Client, so can tailor its response depending on the consumer of the data.

Comment: Is attributeName and attributeValue the same as ClaimType and ClaimValue in your implementation? Is namespacing the claims value like I described above a good solution for avoiding claim conflicts for application specific claims?

Comment: Namespacing the claims is fine, as long as you have the freedom to dictate what claims the clients should expect. In my case, we had ~100 clients all with existing requirements on claim names - we can't ask them all to change!